# how do I install apache portable runtime

Tags: svn, apache, runtime, portability

I am trying to install subversion on a linux machine and get I get and error saying that I don't have APR installed

My question is: how do I install APR and link with with my Apache HTTP server (i have 2.2 running)?

I have looked for documentation for about 2 hours now,...can't find anything...i would also like to mention that i am pretty big unix newb.

Pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Portable Runtime is installed alongside apache server. all you have to do is make sure your LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains path for <APACHEINSTALLDIR>/lib and it will be detected by your svn.